# I'm trying to make the div tag invisible in body background but the div remains visible in the body background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the div tag circle .blad3 the yellow color invisible in the body background color dark blue, but the div remains visible in the body background. I tried with overflow hidden both in body and div and with z-index and background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom ,rgb(...)..%, rgb(...)..% ); tried but the div tag remains visible in the body. In the outline of the div it can be made invisible with z-index. I want to do it with CSS, in body background is a mystery to me.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color:rgb(6, 5, 70);
    min-height: 90%;
    font-size: 8px;
    padding:30px 10px 50px;
}

.drawing {
    position :relative;
    width: 200em;
    height: 100em;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgb(100,167,223);
    outline: 1.5em solid rgb(56, 118, 29);
    outline-offset: -1em;
    z-index: 1;
}

.circle .kern{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 40% 40% / 40% 50% 50% 40%;
    left: 8.4px;
    bottom: 8.5px;
    width: 406px;
    height: 412px;

    }

.circle .circle1{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 40% 40% / 40% 50% 50% 40%;
    left: 8.4px;
    bottom: 8.5px;
    width: 406px;
    height: 412px;
}

.circle .blad1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    bottom: 36px;
    left: -105px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(255, 255, 0)16%, rgb(6, 5, 70)22%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right ,rgb(255, 255, 0)16%, rgb(6, 5, 70)22%);
    filter:contrast(120%);
    transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg) rotateZ(-236.6deg);
    border-radius: 30% 105% 1% 125% / 30% 125% 20% 105%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.circle .blad2{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(50% - 120px);
    height: 80px;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: -33px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(255, 255, 0)62% , rgb(6, 5, 70)35%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right ,rgb(255, 255, 0)62%, rgb(6, 5, 70)35%);
    filter:contrast(120%);
    transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg) rotateZ(-241deg);
    border-radius: 30% 105% 1% 125% / 30% 125% 20% 105%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.circle .blad3{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(50% - 120px);
    height: 80px;
    bottom: -66px;
    left: 35px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left,rgb(255, 255, 0)52%, rgb(6, 5, 70)52% );
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgb(255, 255, 0)52%, rgb(6, 5, 70)52%);
    filter:contrast(120%);
    transform:perspective(100px) rotateX(5deg) rotateZ(-264deg);
    border-radius: 30% 105% 1% 125% / 30% 125% 20% 105%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawing">
    <div class="circle">
        <div class="kern"></div>
        <div class="circle1">
            <div class="blad1"></div>
            <div class="blad2"></div>
            <div class="blad3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking for here.  Which div are you trying to hide?  What does "invisible in body background" mean?

Comment: Hello Daniël, i'm trying hide the <div class="blad3"></div> it remains visible in the body background

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When someone asks you what a phrase you're using means, just reusing that same exact phrase isn't very helpful.    At a guess does "visible in the body background" mean "it's extending outside the boundaries of the green border?"

Comment: If that guess is correct, add "overflow: hidden" to `.drawing`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had tried with .drawing .blad3 but in only in .drawing I had not tried and what I asked is now hidden. That was a good guess on your part!